# Proper Join Query

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

I have a table that has every group (`gid`) a user (`uid`, say 1031, for example) belongs to and another table that has every group that has permission to edit a given document (`pid`). I'm trying to figure out the most efficient query to confirm if the user has the permission to edit the said document (e.g. if the user is in any group that is listed as having editing privileges). It seems like there are usually performance issues in JOIN queries I don't anticipate up front.

This is what I came up with. Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT p.gid
     , p.pid
     , p.r
     , p.w 
  FROM permissions p
  JOIN groups_members m
    ON m.gid = p.gid 
 WHERE groups_members.uid = 1
```

Comment: Questions about performance show include `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` output for every table involved in the SQL.. And also a `EXPLAIN <query>` output for every SQL involved in the question.. Now this is question is unclear and will be most likely be voteclosed.

Comment: "It seems like there are usually performance issues in JOIN queries I don't anticipate up front." Hint: indexes? This query seams to be needing the indexes `groups_members(gid, uid)` and `permissions(gid)`

Comment: Good idea, thank you. I have indexes on the unique id for each table, but not gid and uid in those tables.

Comment: If your queries are mostly analytic, have you considered an analytics-oriented rather a transaction-oriented, DBMS?